# Storing a re-orderable list in a database

Tags: database, database-design, mongodb, postgres

I'm working on a wishlist system, where users can add items to their various wishlists, and I plan to allow users to re-order the items later on. I am not really sure about the best way to go about storing this in a database while remaining fast and not turning in to a mess (this app will be used by a fairly large user base, so I don't want it to go down to clean up stuff).

I initially tried a `position` column, but it seems like that would be quite inefficient having to change every other item's position value when you move them around.

I have seen people using a self-reference to refer to the previous (or next) value, but again, it seems like you would have to update a whole lot of other items in the list.

Another solution I've seen is using decimal numbers and just sticking items in the gaps between them, which seems like the best solution so far, but I'm sure there has to be a better way.

I would say a typical list would contain up to about 20 or so items, and I will probably limit it to 50. The re-ordering would be using drag and drop and will probably be done in batches to prevent race conditions and such from the ajax requests. I'm using postgres (on heroku) if it matters.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers for any help!

Comment: Can you do a bit of benchmarking and tell us whether IO or Database will be a bottleneck?

Comment: Related question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813704/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-store-records-order-in-sql).

Comment: With self-reference, when moving an item from one place in the list to the other you only have to update 2 items. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: Hmm, not sure why linked lists are hardly getting any attention in the answers.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First, don't try to do anything clever with decimal numbers, because they'll spite you.  `REAL` and `DOUBLE PRECISION` are inexact and may not properly represent what you put into them.  `NUMERIC` is exact, but the right sequence of moves will run you out of precision and your implementation will break badly.

Limiting moves to single ups and downs makes the whole operation very easy.  For a list of sequentially-numbered items, you can move an item up by decrementing its position and incrementing the position number of whatever the previous decrement came up with.  (In other words, item `5` would become `4` and what was item `4` becomes `5`, effectively a swap as Morons described in his answer.)  Moving it down would be the opposite.  Index your table by whatever uniquely identifies a list and position and you can do it with two `UPDATE`s inside a transaction that will run very quickly.  Unless your users are rearranging their lists at superhuman speeds, this isn't going to cause much of a load.

Drag-and-drop moves (e.g., move item `6` to sit between items `9` and `10`) are a little trickier and have to be done differently depending on whether the new position is above or below the old one.  In the example above, you have to open up a hole by incrementing all positions greater than `9`, updating item `6`'s position to be the new `10` and then decrementing the position of everything greater than `6` to fill in the vacated spot.  With the same indexing I described before, this will be quick.  You can actually make this go a bit faster than I described by minimizing the number of rows the transaction touches, but that's a microoptimization you don't need until you can prove there's a bottleneck.

Either way, trying to outdo the database with a home-brewed, too-clever-by-half solution doesn't usually lead to success.  Databases worth their salt have been carefully written to do these operations very, very quickly by people who are very, very good at it.

Comment: This is exactly how I handled it in a project bid preparation system we had a gazillion years ago. Even in Access, the update was likety-split fast.

Comment: Thanks for the explination, Blrfl! I did attempt to do the latter option, but I found that if I deleted items from the middle of the list, it would leave gaps in the positions (it was quite a naïve implementation). Is there an easy way to avoid creating gaps like this, or would I have to do it manually each time I re-ordered something (if i have to actually manage it at all)?

Comment: @TomBrunoli:  I'd have to think on the implementation a bit before saying for sure, but you might be able to pull off most or all of the renumbering automagically with triggers.  E.g., if you delete item 7, the trigger decrements all rows in the same list numbered greater than 7 after the delete takes place.  Inserts would do the same thing (inserting an item 7 would increment all rows 7 or higher).  The trigger for an update (e.g., move item 3 between 9 and 10) would be moderately more complex but is certainly within the realm of doable.

Comment: I hadn't actually looked in to triggers before but that seems like a good way to do it.

Comment: @TomBrunoli:  It occurs to me that using triggers to do this may cause cascades.  Stored procedures with all changes in a transaction might be the better route for this.

Comment: Having gaps isn't a problem if you use the 'position' simply to order the result, at least until the gaps become significant compared to the maximum integer value.

Comment: @PeteKirkham:  Interesting point.  Selecting `row_number() OVER ()` would close the gaps during queries, and it wouldn't be difficult to trigger a renumbering when the high value reaches some threshold.  Clients would have to have an identifier for each item, so instead of saying "take the 8th item and insert it after the 17th," they'd have to say "take item ID 12345 and insert it after ID 23456" and the database would have to deal with that.  Might actually be safer in the presence of operations done outside of transactions by multiple clients.

Comment: So true about decimals. This is what i have been trying for ages...

Comment: I agree on the solution in general, but I do not understand why you would like to "lift" the positions after `6`. It would be much easier to move position `6` to some sort of placeholder, let's say position `0`, do the rest of the ordering and then just move position `0` back to position `6`. 

That way, only a few position changes would be needed instead of maybe thousands if you are right at a beginning of a very long list.

Answer (score 89):

Same answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49956113/10608

---

Solution: make `index` a string (because strings, in essence, have infinite "arbitrary precision"). Or if you use an int, increment `index` by 100 instead of 1.

The problem (performance/complexity) being solved by this solution: there is no "in between" values between two sorted items.

```
item      index
-----------------
gizmo     1
              <<------ Oh no! no room between 1 and 2.
                       This requires incrementing _every_ item after it
gadget    2
gear      3
toolkit   4
box       5
```

Instead, do something like this (with a better solution below):

```
item      index
-----------------
gizmo     100
              <<------ Sweet :). I can re-order 99 (!) items here
                       without having to change anything else
gadget    200
gear      300
toolkit   400
box       500
```

Even better: here is how Jira solves this problem. Their "rank" (what you call index) is a string value that allows a ton of breathing room in between ranked items.

Here is a real example of a jira database I work with

```
   id    | jira_rank
---------+------------
 AP-2405 | 0|hzztxk:
 ES-213  | 0|hzztxs:
 AP-2660 | 0|hzztzc:
 AP-2688 | 0|hzztzk:
 AP-2643 | 0|hzztzs:
 AP-2208 | 0|hzztzw:
 AP-2700 | 0|hzztzy:
 AP-2702 | 0|hzztzz:
 AP-2411 | 0|hzztzz:i
 AP-2440 | 0|hzztzz:r
```

Notice this example `hzztzz:i`. The advantage of a string rank is that you run out of room between two items, you *still* don't have to re-rank anything else. You just start appending more characters to the string to narrow down focus.

Comment: I was trying to come up with some way to do this by only updating a single record, and this answer explains the solution I was thinking up in my head very well.

Comment: I vote for this solution. And for those concerned about an edge case where  we end up with too long strings (so long that their impact becomes noticeable from the point of memory and efficiency of Jira-scale DB?..) - you can always implement a background job that periodically (say, once a week) goes over these ranks and normalizes them. Provided that we're only interested in their relative values, not absolute.

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: Atlassian has an interesting video about their lexical ranking: https://youtu.be/OjQv9xMoFbg

Comment: @Rockiger is there any text document about LexoRank available? I found that video incredibly hard to follow...

Comment: Not, that I know of.

Comment: @Rockiger were you able to find any more info on lexoranking? I also watched the video and it's hard to get a complete picture out of it. I can't seem to make heads of it.

Comment: No, I am afraid not.

Answer (score 22):

> "but it seems like that would be quite inefficient"

Did you *measure* that? Or is that just a guess? Don't make such assumptions without any proof.

> "20 to 50 items per list"

Honestly, that is not "a whole lot of items", to me that sounds just very few.

I suggest you stick to the "position column" approach (if that's the most simple implementation for you). For such small list sizes, don't start unnecessary optimizing before you experience real performance problems

Answer (score 15):

> I have seen people using a self-reference to refer to the previous (or
>   next) value, but again, it seems like you would have to update a whole
>   lot of other items in the list.

Why? Say you take a linked-list table approach with columns (listID, itemID, nextItemID).

Inserting a new item into a list costs one insert, and one modified row.

Repositioning an item costs three row modifications (the item being moved, the item before it, and the item before its new location).

Removing an item costs one delete and one modified row.

These costs remain the same regardless of whether the list has 10 items or 10,000 items. In all three cases there's one less modification if the target row is the first list item. If you're more often operating on the *last* list item it may be beneficial to store prevItemID rather than next.

Comment: What about reading the list in order?

Comment: @MiguelCarvajal more importantly, what about reading 100 items from the middle of a 10,000 item list

Answer (score 14):

OK I face this tricky problem recently, and all the answers in this Q&A post gave many inspiration. The way I see it, each solution has its pros and cons.

- If the `position` field has to be sequential without gaps, then you will basically need to re-order the entire list. This is an O(N) operation. The advantage is that the client side would not need any special logic to obtain the order.
- If we want to avoid the O(N) operation BUT STILL maintain a precise sequence, one of the approach is to use "self-reference to refer to the previous (or next) value". This is a textbook linked list scenario. By design, it will NOT incur "a whole lot of other items in the list". However, this requires the client-side (a web service or perhaps a mobile app) to implement the linked-list travesal logic to derive the order.
- Some variation does not use reference i.e. linked list. They choose to represent the entire order as a self-contained blob, such as a JSON-array-in-a-string `[5,2,1,3,...]`; such order will then be stored in a separated place. This approach also has a side effect of requiring the client side code to maintain that separated order blob.
- In many cases, we do not really need to store the exact order, we just need to maintain a relative rank among each record. Therefore we can allow gaps between sequential records. Variations includes: (1) using integer with gaps such as 100, 200, 300... but you will quickly run out of gaps and then need the recover process; (2) [using decimal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/195317/114874) which comes with natural gaps, but you will need to decide whether you can live with the eventual precision limitation; (3) using string-based rank as described in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/369754/114874) but be careful the [tricky implementation traps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536262/best-representation-of-an-ordered-list-in-a-database#comment88663355_49956113).
- The real answer can be "it depends". Revisit your business requirement. For example, if it is a wish list system, personally I would happily use a system organizes by just few ranks as "must-have", "good-to-have", "maybe-later", and then present items without particular order inside each rank. If it is a delivering system, you can very well use the delivery time as a rough rank which comes with natural gap (and natural conflict prevention as no delivery would happen at the same time). Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 12):

Use a floating point number for the position column.

You can then reorder the list changing only the position column in the "moved" row.

Basically if your user wants to position "red" after "blue" but before "yellow"

Then you just need to calculate

```
red.position = ((yellow.position - blue.position) / 2) + blue.position
```

After a few million re-positions you may get floating point numbers so small that there is no "between" -- but this is about as likely as sighting a unicorn.

You could implement this using an integer field with an initial gap of say 1000. So your intial oredring would be 1000->blue,2000->Yellow,3000->Red.
After "moving" Red after blue you would have 1000->blue,1500->Red,2000->Yellow.

The problem is that with a seemingly large initial gap of 1000 as few as 10 moves will get you into a situation like 1000->blue,1001-puce,1004->biege ...... where you will no longer be able to insert anything after "blue" without re-number the whole list. Using floating point numbers there will always be a "halfway" point between the two positions.

Comment: Indexing and sorting in a datbase based on floats is [more expensive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360824/is-there-a-speed-difference-in-ordering-by-int-vs-float) than ints.  Ints also are a nice ordinal type... doesn't need to be sent as bits to be able to be sorted on the client (the difference between two numbers that render the same when printed, but have different bit values).

Comment: But any scheme using ints means you need to update all/most of the rows in the list every time the order changes. Using floats you only update the row which moved. Also "floats more expensive than ints" very much depends on the implementation and hardware used. Certainly the extra cpu involved is insignificant compared with the cpu required to update a row and its associated indexes.

Comment: Using gaps is a blueprint for disaster. Your gaps act like a binary search and will at any larger scale prove to be insufficient.

Comment: Also the difference between using an integer and a floating point number is non-existant. It's about the "bittness". A 32 bit float will run into issues just as fast as a 32 bit integer. You would need like a 64 bit float, but then, why not use a 64 bit integer?

Comment: For the naysayers, this solution is exactly what Trello (https://trello.com) does. Open up your chrome debugger and diff the json output from before/after a reorder (drag/drop a card) and you get - `"pos": 1310719,
+  "pos": 638975.5`. To be fair, most people don't do trello lists with 4 million entries in them, but Trello's list size & use case is pretty common for user-sortable content. And anything user-sortable has approximately nothing to do with high performance, int vs float sorting speed is moot for that, especially considering databases are mostly constrained by IO performance.

Comment: @PieterB As for 'why not use a 64 bit integer', it's mostly ergonomics for the developer, I would say. There is approximately as much bit depth <1.0 as there is >1.0 for your average float, so you can default the 'position' column to 1.0 and insert 0.5, 0.25, 0.75 just as easily as doubling. With integers, your default would have to be 2^30 or so, makes it a bit tricky to think about when you're debugging. Is 4073741824 bigger than 496359787? Start counting digits.

Comment: Furthermore, if you ever hit a case where you run out of space between numbers... it's not that hard to fix. Move one of them. But the important thing is that this works in a best-effort kind of way, which handles many concurrent edits by different parties (e.g. trello). You can split two numbers, maybe even sprinkle a bit of random noise, and voila, even if someone else did the same thing at the same time there is still a global order, and you didn't need to INSERT inside a transaction to get there.

Comment: @user40980 If I understand correctly - For mongo - if you index your column then that "inefficiency" is not peneltied upon reading only upon writing the data.

Comment: Another possibility is to use an asci string -- start with Blue - "A",  Red "B" and Green "C" to add purple between Blue and Red give it the code "AJ" ro add pink between Purple and Red give it the code "AP", eventually you could end up with a code like "AKELA" after thousands of inserts.

Answer (score 7):

**This is really a question of scale, and use case..**

How many items do you expect in a list?
If millions, i think gong the decimal route is the obvious one.

If 6 then integers renumbering is the obvious choice.
s
Also the questions is *how* the lists or rearranged. If you are using a up and down arrows (moving up or down one slot at a time), the i would use integers then swap with the prev (or next) on move.

Also how often do you commit, if the user can make 250 changes then commit at once, than i say integers with renumbering again...

**tl;dr: Need more info.**

---

Edit: "Wish lists" sounds like a lot of small lists (assumption, this may be false).. So I say Integer with renumbering. 
(Each list contains its own Postion)

Comment: I'll update the question with some more context

Comment: decimals don't work, as the precision is limited, and each inserted item potentially takes 1 bit

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the question is rather old and already has a couple of answers. Still, all of the solutions offered here are pretty complex. How about some simpler ones?

The original question is about Wish List - something that likely has number of items in tens, maybe hundreds - but not thousands, usually. Why not then store the sort order in a single text field as a **serialized array**? Any insert, update and delete would only affect one extra record this way.

If a serialized array is not fancy enough, you can always make it a JSON field, but it will still be just one cell that is being modified in the database.

Comment: +1 Especially if there is not much data associated with each item on the list (perhaps just a short textual label).

Answer (score 3):

If the objective is to minimize number of database operations per reordering operation:

Assuming that

- All shopping items can be enumerated with 32-bit integers.
- There is a maximum size limit for a user's wish list. (I saw some popular website use 20 - 40 items as limit)

Store the user's sorted wish list as a packed sequence of integers (integer arrays) in one column. Every time the wish list is reordered, the entire array (single row; single column) is updated - which is to be performed with a single SQL update.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

---

If the objective is different, stick with the "position column" approach.

---

Regarding the "speed", make sure to benchmark the stored procedure approach. While issuing 20+ *separate* updates for one wish list shuffle may be slow, there might be a fast way using stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

While the OP briefly touched on the notion of using a Linked-List to store sort-order, it has a lot of advantages for cases where items will be reordered frequently.

> I have seen people using a self-reference to refer to the previous (or next) value, but again, it seems like you would have to update a whole lot of other items in the list.

The thing is - **you don't**! When using a linked-list, insertion, deletion, and re-ordering are `O(1)` operations, and database-imposed referential integrity ensures there aren't any broken references, orphaned records, or loops.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Wishlists (
  WishlistId int           NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  [Name]     nvarchar(200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE WishlistItems (
  ItemId     int           NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  WishlistId int           NOT NULL,
  Text       nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
  SortAfter  int               NULL,

  CONSTRAINT PK_WishlistItem PRIMARY KEY ( ItemId, WishlistId ),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Wishlist_WishlistItem FOREIGN KEY ( WishlistId ) REFERENCES Wishlists ( WishlistId ),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Sorting FOREIGN KEY ( SortAfter, WishlistId ) REFERENCES WishlistItems ( ItemId, WishlistId )
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_Sorting ON WishlistItems ( SortAfter, WishlistId );

 -----

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Wishlists ON;

INSERT INTO Wishlists ( WishlistId, [Name] ) VALUES
  ( 1, 'Wishlist 1' ),
  ( 2, 'Wishlist 2' );

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Wishlists OFF;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT WishlistItems ON;

INSERT INTO WishlistItems ( ItemId, WishlistId, [Text], SortAfter ) VALUES
( 1, 1, 'One', NULL ),
( 2, 1, 'Two', 1 ),
( 3, 1, 'Three', 2 ),
( 4, 1, 'Four', 3 ),
( 5, 1, 'Five', 4 ),
( 6, 1, 'Six', 5 ),
( 7, 1, 'Seven', 6 ),
( 8, 1, 'Eight', 7 );

SET IDENTITY_INSERT WishlistItems OFF;
```

Note the following:

- Using a composite primary-key and foreign-key in `FK_Sorting` to prevent items from accidentally referring to the wrong parent item.
- The `UNIQUE INDEX UX_Sorting` performs two roles:

  - As it allows a single `NULL` value each list can have only 1 "head" item.
  - It prevents two or more items from claiming to be in the same sorting place (by preventing duplicate `SortAfter` values).

The main advantages to this approach:

- Never requires rebalancing or maintenance - as with `int` or `real`-based sort-orders that eventually run out of space between items after frequent reordering.
- Only items that are re-ordered (and their siblings) need to be updated.

This approach does have disadvantages, however:

- You can only sort this list in SQL using a Recursive CTE because you cannot do a straightforward `ORDER BY`.

  - As a workaround, you could create a wrapper `VIEW` or TVF that uses a CTE to add a derived containing an incrementing sort-order - but this would be expensive to use in large operations.
- You must load the entire list into your program in order to display it - you cannot operate on a subset of the rows because then the `SortAfter` column will refer to items that aren't loaded into your program.

  - However loading all items for a list is easy due to the composite primary key (i.e. just do `SELECT * FROM WishlistItems WHERE WishlistId = @wishlistToLoad`).
- Performing any operation while `UX_Sorting` is enabled requires DBMS support for Deferred Constraints.

  - **i.e.** the ideal implementation of this approach won't work in SQL Server until they add-back support for Deferrable Constraints and indexes.
  - A workaround is to make the Unique Index a Filtered Index that allows multiple `NULL` values in the column - which unfortunately means that a List *could* have multiple HEAD items.

    - A workaround-for-this-workaround is to add a third column `State` which is a simple flag to declare if a list item is "active" or not - and the unique index ignores inactive items.
  - This is something SQL Server used to support back in the 1990s and then they inexplicably removed support for it.

### Workaround 1: Need ability to perform a trivial `ORDER BY`.

Here's a VIEW using a recursive CTE that adds a `SortOrder` column:

```
CREATE VIEW OrderableWishlistItems AS 

    WITH c ( ItemId, WishlistId, [Text], SortAfter, SortOrder )
    AS
    (
        SELECT
              ItemId, WishlistId, [Text], SortAfter, 1 AS SortOrder
        FROM
              WishlistItems
        WHERE
              SortAfter IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
              i.ItemId, i.WishlistId, i.[Text], i.SortAfter, c.SortOrder + 1
        FROM
              WishlistItems AS i
              INNER JOIN c ON
                  i.WishlistId = c.WishlistId
                  AND
                  i.SortAfter = c.ItemId
    )
    SELECT
        ItemId, WishlistId, [Text], SortAfter, SortOrder
    FROM
        c;
```

You can use this VIEW in other queries where you need to sort values using `ORDER BY`:

```
Query:

    SELECT * FROM OrderableWishlistItems

Results:

    ItemId  WishlistId  Text        SortAfter   SortOrder
    1       1           One         (null)      1
    2       1           Two             1       2
    3       1           Three           2       3
    4       1           Four            3       4
    5       1           Five            4       5
    6       1           Six             5       6
    7       1           Seven           6       7
    8       1           Eight           7       8
```

### Workaround 2: Preventing `UNIQUE INDEX` violation constraints when performing operations:

Add a `State` column to the `WishlistItems` table. The column is marked as `HIDDEN` so most ORM tools (like Entity Framework) won't include it when generating models, for example.

```
CREATE TABLE WishlistItems (
  ItemId     int           NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  WishlistId int           NOT NULL,
  Text       nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
  SortAfter  int               NULL,
  [State]    bit           NOT NULL HIDDEN,

  CONSTRAINT PK_WishlistItem PRIMARY KEY ( ItemId, WishlistId ),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Wishlist_WishlistItem FOREIGN KEY ( WishlistId ) REFERENCES Wishlists ( WishlistId ),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Sorting FOREIGN KEY ( SortAfter, WishlistId ) REFERENCES WishlistItems ( ItemId, WishlistId )
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_Sorting ON WishlistItems ( SortAfter, WishlistId ) WHERE [State] = 1;
```

### Operations:

#### Adding a new item to the tail end of the list:

1. Load the list first to determine the `ItemId` of the current last item in the list and store in `@tailItemId` - or use `SELECT MAX( SortOrder ) FROM OrderableWishlistItems WHERE WishlistId = @listId`.
2. `INSERT INTO WishlistItems ( WishlistId, [Text], SortAfter ) VALUES ( @listId, @text, @tailItemId )`.

#### Reordering item 4 to be below item 7

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @itemIdToMove int = 4
    DECLARE @itemIdToMoveAfter int = 7

    DECLARE @prev int = ( SELECT SortAfter FROM WishlistItems WHERE ItemId = @itemIdToMove )

    UPDATE WishlistItems SET [State] = 0 WHERE ItemId IN ( @itemIdToMove , @itemIdToMoveAfter )

    UPDATE WishlistItems SET [SortAfter] = @itemIdToMove WHERE ItemId = @itemIdToMoveAfter 

    UPDATE WishlistItems SET [SortAfter] = @prev WHERE SortAfter = @itemIdToMove 

    UPDATE WishlistItems SET [State] = 1 WHERE ItemId IN ( @itemIdToMove, @itemIdToMoveAfter )

COMMIT;
```

#### Removing item 4 from the middle of the list:

If an item is at the tail end of the list (i.e. where `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM WishlistItems WHERE SortAfter = @itemId )`) then you can do a single `DELETE`.

If an item has an item sorted after it, you perform the same steps as reordering an item, except you `DELETE` it afterwards instead of setting `State = 1;`.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @itemIdToRemove int = 4

    DECLARE @prev int = ( SELECT SortAfter FROM WishlistItems WHERE ItemId = @itemIdToRemove )

    UPDATE WishlistItems SET [State] = 0 WHERE ItemId = @itemIdToRemove

    UPDATE WishlistItems SET [SortAfter] = @prev WHERE SortAfter = @itemIdToRemove

    DELETE FROM WishlistItems WHERE ItemId = @itemIdToRemove

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254909/how-to-make-a-postgres-function-reorder-rows-representing-a-linked-list? It is related to your solution but I can't get it to work.